# how to have puma send logs to stdout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

i want my RoR/puma logs to just go to stdout instead of a log file. is it as simple as removing the `stdout_redirect` line from my puma configs (aka, `puma.rb`)?

Comment: Literally yes, if you want `puma`'s log output, not `rails`' one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Rails 5, just set RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=1 from command line

Answer (score -3):

Check the example config file https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/examples/config.rb#L49

go and find `/u/apps/lolcat/log/stderr` true or false if false make as true

```
stdout_redirect '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stdout', '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stderr'
stdout_redirect '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stdout', '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stderr', true
```

Comment: if i am reading this correctly, setting the 3rd parameter to true just makes the output appended ... but like it will still write the files specified in the 1st two parameters. i need this to just output to stdout